# If date has passed in this year, get it from next year

Tags: php, php-carbon

I'm using Carbon for the dates. Let's take 1st of March for example. By default Carbon returns the 1st of March for the current year.

```
//Returns current year value
$date = Carbon::parse('first day of March');
```

Is it possible to get it definitely from the future (next year), if it has already passed in this year, without using if conditions.

```
//Shorten this part
$date = Carbon::parse('first day of March');
if ($date->lessThanOrEqualTo(Carbon::now())) {
  $date->addYear();
}
$output = $date->format('d-m-Y');
```

Comment: _"..., __if__ it has already.." - "without using __if__ condition"_

Answer (score 1):

Carbon is just a wrapper class for PHP's DateTime class.

Therefore, this should work:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('2018-03-01');
$today = new DateTime();
if ($date < $today) {
    $date->modify('+1 year');
}
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

Output: `01/03/2019`

See it working here https://3v4l.org/i1HvL

Learn the actual PHP DateTime class here https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

I have no idea why you wouldn't use if to check IF something. Maybe you'd like a ternary better?

```
$date = ($date < $today) ? $date->modify('+1 year') : $date;
```

Comment: The code OP posted works, but he/she wants to not use the if()

Comment: Ternary is an if.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not cleaner than your method, but it's different and it's working.
I create an array with all the dates relevant, today, 1 of March, and 1 of March next year and sort them.
Then I find 'today' with array_search in the array and grab the next value.

```
$date = array(Carbon::parse('today'),Carbon::parse('first day of March'), Carbon::parse('first day of March + 1 year')); 
sort($date);
$date = $date[array_search(Carbon::parse('today'), $date)+1];
var_dump($date);
```

I honestly think this is slower than a if(), but it does not use an if() as OP requested :-)

Comment: I was kinda hoping changing the string "first day of March" would help. "first day of next March" or something like that.